# How to get id name using javascript on select tag?

Tags: javascript, html

How to get `id` name using javascript on `select` tag ?

This is my code, when i tested it alerts `undefined`.

for example when i selected `bbb` in select tag i'll alert `2`

How can i do it?

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvy8mkk6/)

```
<select id="test" onchange="test_fn()">
   <option id="1" value="11">aaa</option>
   <option id="2" value="22">bbb</option>
   <option id="3" value="33">ccc</option>
</select>



<script type="text/javascript">
function test_fn()
{
    alert(this.id);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

In fact you just need   `select.options[select.selectedIndex].id`, and pass the `select` element as an argument to your function using `this` keyword.

```js
function test_fn(select)
{
  console.log("ddd");
    alert(select.options[select.selectedIndex].id);
}
```

```html
<select id="test" onchange="test_fn(this)">
<option id="1" value="11">aaa</option>
<option id="2" value="22">bbb</option>
<option id="3" value="33">ccc</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @mongmongseesee IE 7 is dead. MS stopped giving updates to them.

Comment: Yes of course you can, but like @RajaprabhuAravindasamy said just  use IE8 or greater.

Comment: @chsdk -- Could you please tell me how to apply this code for IE7 ?

Comment: May I ask you why do you want to use IE7? Otherwise just run it on IE it think it will work as expected.

Comment: my user usually use ie7 on license windows.

Comment: But IE7 is no longer supported by almost all new Windows operating systems.

Comment: but my corporate not purchase a new window. ^^ now they use win vista.

Comment: Ok then, I think this code will work perfectly even with IE7.